# Can't check for null line in list after first parse

Tags: python, list, csv, null

I am parsing a route table from a Cisco.  I need only the BGP entries.  There are a few oddball OSPF routes which make the line different.  I don't care about those.  But because the line split[8:10] is different my final write is an empty line.  I write it to be network, netmask of 0.0.0.0) but I'd like skip blank lines on the final write. This is an example of the file, and the code to parse it.  As the actual files are huge I am trying to avoid repetitive loops.

EDIT: The goal is to write a csv file of 2 columns which have the IP address and the netmask.

```
B        10.34.86.0/24 [20/0] via 10.15.33.73, 2w3d
B        10.34.93.0/24 [20/0] via 10.15.33.73, 2w3d
O E1     10.34.95.0/24  <- DON'T CARE ABOUT HIM  
B        10.34.97.0/24 [20/0] via 10.15.33.73, 2w0d
B        10.34.98.0/24 [20/0] via 10.15.33.73, 2w3d
```

Desired Output (notice the O line is not there)

10.34.86.0,24
10.34.93.0,24
10.34.97.0,24
10.34.98.0,24

And my Python 3

```
import csv
import re
import time
timestr = time.strftime("%m%d%y")
with open('RemediationStatus' + timestr + '.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    with open('routes-3-28.txt','r')as msroutes:
        headwrite = csv.writer(csvfile)
        headwrite.writerow(["Network", "Netmask"])
        for line in msroutes:
            firstpass = re.split(r'[\s,/]', line)
            finalpass = (firstpass[8:10])
            if not finalpass[0]:
                finalpass = (["0.0.0.0", "0.0.0.0"])
        print(finalpass)
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(finalpass)
```

Comment: For those of us who are not familiar with BGP and OSPF, what's your desired output?

Comment: to grab the network and netmask (the IP/xx like 2nd line I want 10..34.93.0 as one column and the 24 as the other column.  The final file ends up as just two columns of network, netmask

Comment: And how do you know the ignore the line you said you don't care about?

Comment: because the split along white space is different so I end up with blank lines after my parse so the line that starts with O and has an extra value of E2 before the IP/Mask throws off my count.  So when I parse that line I end up with an empty line in the resulting list.

Comment: I think this can be done with a simple regex, but I'm still not 100% clear on your desired output. Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49576834/edit) your question and show the full desired output for your example input file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take advantage of `re` module in python and if I caught your logic you want something like this :

```
import re

text = ''''B        10.34.86.0/24 [20/0] via 10.15.33.73, 2w3d
B        10.34.93.0/24 [20/0] via 10.15.33.73, 2w3d
O E1     10.34.95.0/24  <- DON'T CARE ABOUT HIM  
B        10.34.97.0/24 [20/0] via 10.15.33.73, 2w0d
B        10.34.98.0/24 [20/0] via 10.15.33.73, 2w3d'''

result = re.findall('B\s+(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\/(\d+)', text)
result
#[('10.34.86.0', '24'),
# ('10.34.93.0', '24'),
# ('10.34.97.0', '24'),
# ('10.34.98.0', '24')]
```

Comment: That's what I want!  Of course, do it all in one Regex pattern not two.  There's my logic flaw.  Final question as there could be a 'B' else where (unlikely but possible) and I want the B at the start of the line is ^B Ok here?

Comment: Sure you can, but this pattern will look for `B` followed by one or more `spaces` and `ip` and so on which should cover you.

Comment: Follow up comment.  This actually results in a list of tuples due to the 2+ regex group.  It threw me for a bit but the awesome versitility of this made me plow through it and figure out I need to iterate the list and then iterate the tuple to write it as a proper csv.  But with this I can now look for ANY patterns in a cisco output of routes.  This method becomes a generic tool for looking for ANY routing patterns.  The only catch was to up my game working with tuples which really I still don't get the value of versus a list.  They seem the same aside from one is mutable and one not.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC here is a way using regex:

```
full_pattern = r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/\d{1,3} \[\d+/\d+]"
small_pattern = r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/\d{1,3}"

msroutes = [
    "B        10.34.86.0/24 [20/0] via 10.15.33.73, 2w3d",
    "B        10.34.93.0/24 [20/0] via 10.15.33.73, 2w3d",
    "O E1     10.34.95.0/24",
    "B        10.34.97.0/24 [20/0] via 10.15.33.73, 2w0d",
    "B        10.34.98.0/24 [20/0] via 10.15.33.73, 2w3d"
]

for line in msroutes:
    finalpass = re.findall(full_pattern, line)
    if finalpass:
        finalpass = re.findall(small_pattern, finalpass[0])
        finalpass = finalpass[0].split('/')
        print(finalpass)

#['10.34.86.0', '24']
#['10.34.93.0', '24']
#['10.34.97.0', '24']
#['10.34.98.0', '24']
```

Since I am not sure if there is an easier way to ignore the line you asked to ignore (perhaps checking to see if it starts with a `'B'` vs starting with `'O'`?), I do two regex searches. The first one looks for something similar to the pattern:

```
##.##.##.##/## [##/#]
```

Where the `#` represents a number. The pattern `\d{1,3}` means match between 1 and 3 digits. This will eliminate the line that does not have `[20/0]` in it.

Next, for the matching lines, I do the smaller regex search to just get the IP and Mask values. We don't have to do error checking on this one because we know it already matched the larger pattern.

---

If you know you only want to process lines that start with `'B'`:

```
for line in msroutes:
    if line.startswith('B'):
        finalpass = re.findall(small_pattern, line)[0].split('/')
        print(finalpass)
#['10.34.86.0', '24']
#['10.34.93.0', '24']
#['10.34.97.0', '24']
#['10.34.98.0', '24']
```

---

Instead of a long regex pattern, you could also just use your existing code and simplify the logic by treating consecutive whitespace as one.

```
for line in msroutes:
    firstpass = re.split(r'\s+', line)
    if len(firstpass) > 1 and "/" in firstpass[1]:
        finalpass = firstpass[1].split("/")
    else:
        finalpass = ["0.0.0.0", "0.0.0.0"]
    print(finalpass)
#['10.34.86.0', '24']
#['10.34.93.0', '24']
#['0.0.0.0', '0.0.0.0']
#['10.34.97.0', '24']
#['10.34.98.0', '24']
```

`\s+` means match one or more spaces.